# Image Gallery with Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to make a simple image gallery app with Ionic. I don't want to get them from the internet or from the camera. I want to get the images from my device and show them. And in something like a grid with two images per row.

I tried to do that with [Ionic Photo Library](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-library/) but it didnt't work. It only showed that broke image icon.

Can someone help me please?

**Update 11/26/2018**

I tried to use Ionic Photo Library like it's described at GitHub again and I noticed that I'm getting the informations about the images. The problem is to show those images at the View. I do exactly as it is showed there but I get this error in console:

```
GET "path_of_image" net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Answer (score 0):

[sample 1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjK5sqesfHeAhUEBywKHYN5BBkQwqsBMAB6BAgFEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DBGoL0uWRTrY&usg=AOvVaw1acoAAbNhrfmeC8XT2TsiA)

[sample 2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjK5sqesfHeAhUEBywKHYN5BBkQwqsBMAF6BAgFEAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DWa6QXQj6UaM&usg=AOvVaw0eniuYTfmshzOgbExyCfiZ)

[sample 3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjK5sqesfHeAhUEBywKHYN5BBkQwqsBMAJ6BAgFEAo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dmjs8x3a9_-4&usg=AOvVaw2rksLoOCC_msngRa-o41u_)

you can check

Comment: Thanks for the help but I already saw those. The problem is that I don't want to put the images inside the project. I want to get images that are in my device. Like the photos that I've taken or downloaded.